# Use function from another file in Django views.py

Tags: python, django

I've created a whole function in my Django views.py and it works. It looks like this:

```
SOME IMPORTS

def get_campaigns(request):

SOME CODE

    campaign_data = []

    for batch in stream:
        for row in batch.results:
            data = {}
            data["campaign_id"] = row.campaign.id
            data["campaign_name"] = row.campaign.name
            campaign_data.append(data)

    return render(request, 'hello/get.html',{ 'data' : data })
```

But then I learned that having your whole functions on views.py is not a good practice at all. I should move the "big" functions to a different file and then call them on views.py, right?

So I tried different options and the only one that worked for me is copying exactly that same code on a different file and then adding to my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    data = get_campaigns(request),
    return render(request, 'index.html',{ 'data' : data })
```

So I'm repeating the same line (return render...) in both files. It works, but looks very ugly and maybe it's slow, buggy or even insecure.

Is there a better solution?

P.D: As you can guess from my question, I'm a complete beginner and I don't really know what I'm doing, so any pointers to beginner-friendly tutorials related to this are much appreciated.

Comment: Is this `get_campaigns` function used in multiple views/functions or just in this single place? I don't understand the advice you received, there is nothing inherently wrong with having a long view and if that code is only repeated once then a separate function just makes reading it harder as you have to jump around

Comment: I agree. Functional based programming works well when a function has a particular focus. Thus, you could look at your functions in `views.py` and refactor the code to be more *functional*. However, I don't see that a long view as inherently a bad thing. Is your code readable? Is your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)? This is where functions are useful as they allow code to be made more DRY. As yet I've not seen a clear use-case to call functions from other files. While that can be done, if the function is a part of that app's application logic then it belongs in that app's `views.py`.

Comment: Thanks! Then I will be moving back the function to views.py, because I don't plan on using it in other places and I'm having other problems that could be more difficult to troubleshoot with extra files and code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what code is going where, but I understand your issue. I remember writing a HUGE views.py when I started.

I think what you've done is OK. You can also define the request for a get, post, etc. Good practice.

I assume in your function which you're importing simply performs the data stream and doesn't render the page. You leave that to the view.py ?

Apologies for not commenting and answering, my reputation score doesn't allow me too yet.

Comment: I was rendering the page in both files (I included the line "return render(request, 'hello/get.html',{ 'data' : data })" in views.py and also in the new .py file). That was my main question (if there was a better solution than repeating the same line in both files). I thought it worked OK, but I discovered today that it's only showing part of the data, not the whole data stream. But I think it's a problem with the function itself (maybe the context for the render), not related to having it in 2 different files. Maybe I will open a new question for that if I'm unable to solve it. Thanks anyway!